# Transform max of sum into sum of max

Tags: reference-request, optimization

Let $f_i : X \times Y \to \mathbb R$, $i=1,2$. Under what conditions is the following true?
$$\max_{x,y} \sum_i f_i(x,y) = \sum_i \max_{x,y} f_i(x,y)$$

Addendum: no math background and was wondering if there exists some general theorem.

**Edit:** Counterexample

Let $f_1 = x$ and $f_2 = y$ subject to $x+y=1 \Rightarrow f_2 = 1-x$. Now the conjecture becomes 
\begin{align}
\max_{x\in[0,1]}\{x + (1-x)\} &= \max_{x\in[0,1]}\{x\} + \max_{x\in[0,1]}\{1-x\}\\
1&=1 +1
\end{align}

Comment: I would guess that it is unlikely to be true with any degree of useful generality?

Comment: Assume the functions attain their maximums at points in $X\times Y$.  It is true if and only if $f_1(x,y)$ and $f_2(x,y)$ attain their maximum at the same "point" $(x,y)$.

Comment: That is, if $\arg\max f_1 = \arg\max f_2$?

Comment: Pretty much.  We only need existence of a common point where $f_1,f_2$ attain their maximums, not that there is a unique such point common to both functions.